# Jquery div and class conflict

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, class

I'm having some trouble with my jquery ajax code.
I have 2 functions, one that will submit a value and other that will update the values in real time.. At least that's what it is supposed to do. :P

So, I have a list that is created throught some PHP code:

```
<div id="votos">
    <ul class="yourvotes">Your votes: 0</ul>
    <li class="votesofothers">
        <a href="#" class="votar" id="3124" iduser="3124" rel="Votar">User</a>  Votes: (0)</br>
        <a href="#" class="votar" id="3125" iduser="3125" rel="Votar">User2</a>  Votes: (0)</br>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then I have a Ajax call to update the database when one of the links is pressed:

```
$(function(){
    $('.votar').click(function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "votar.php",
            data: "id="+elem.attr('iduser'),
            dataType:"json",  
            success: function() {
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
            window.location.reload();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And this would be the code to update the values that appear in "real-time":

```
function mostrarvotos() {
    $('#votos').load('votos.php');
    setTimeout('mostrarvotos()',1000);
}
mostrarvotos();
```

(I originally wanted to update each of the user votes instead of updating the whole div but I couldn't manage to do it.)

So my problem is that when I add the "mostrarvotos()" function to my code the links stop working and just add a # to the url, but if I remove it everything works fine.. If you could help me with this I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Why are you using AJAX AND reloading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are not prevent the link's original action.  The click handler won't catch the event when you refreshed the content with an AJAX request. Try `document.on` instead of your current handler:

```
$(document).on('click','.votar',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default action
    var elem = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "votar.php",
        data: "id="+elem.attr('iduser'),
        dataType:"json",  
        success: function() {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Also note the `preventDefault` which prevents the defauls link action (the # in your address bar).

Comment: @SteveGarret This is called delegation, you should always delegate when working with dynamic content (like both S.Pols and putvande do). But I think your problem was that you forgot the `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate your click function because you are adding those links dynamically.
So do something like:

```
$(function () {
    // delegate your dynamically loaded links
    $('#votos').on('click', '.votor', function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "votar.php",
            data: "id=" + elem.attr('iduser'),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            window.location.reload();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```